# What (beside tags) makes a question appear on the front page?

Tags: discussion, homepage

Sometimes I get questions on my Stack Overflow front page, and I don't understand why. I mainly use the site in the [android](/questions/tagged/android),[java](/questions/tagged/java) tags, with some light [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) activity added recently.

Today, I've got plenty of Android/Java questions on the front page, but also some that I just don't understand. For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19051311/752320), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19050609/752320). One is tagged with [dynamics-crm](/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm)[dynamics-crm-2011](/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-2011), the other with [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4). I've never used these tags, so what makes them appear?

I know about the [Tag Future Report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current), but mine doesn't show anything related. I even browsed my profile's tag listing, but it turns out I've never asked or answered *a single question* for any of the three.

So my question is, why are they there? I don't browse [ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)-related tags, and I don't use [Dynamics CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM) at all, so no action there either. It can't be based on being a "popular" question, because they both have zero votes and low views (at this time).

The questions aren't even topically related to my main tags as far as I can tell. Is there some sort of question scanning algorithm that lumps things together even with differing tags?

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/ for some details. Not sure how up-to-date that still is.

Comment: Thanks. I knew this info had to be *somewhere*, I just couldn't find it on MSO. Exactly what I was looking for, assuming it *is* up-to-date. I'd be interested if anyone knows of a more recent change.

Comment: Geobits: http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/ might be more recent (/cc @Bart).

Comment: @Matt An interesting read, and it explains more about the Tag Future feature. Like I said, though, none of the tags in question show up there.

Comment: @Geobits: See [this comment](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/#comment-241); SE throw a few random questions in there.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the find, I couldn't find it searching(the title is pretty vague). The answer is pretty outdated, though, according to the blog post Matt linked. Should I just move my answer over there?

Comment: @GenericHolidayName Meh, the blog is generally the most discoverable answer to the question, unfortunately one cannot close as a duplicate of it.  There are *lots* of meta questions that are essentially duplicates that just link/quote the blog.  I just picked a duplicate at random.  Note that this is the "interesting" tab, not strictly the homepage, which is likely why you had trouble searching for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like "unanswered" questions in my profile, so I'll sum up some details from the links in comments. Thanks to Bart and Matt for the pointers to them.

### It's **mostly** tags...

From [Kevin Montrose's post](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/), you can see a general overview of how they select what tags to show you.

- Only counts tags used on more than **forty** questions total
- Only counts tags on questions you **answered**, not questions you *ask*
- Only counts tags where you have at least **three** answers
- **Your** tag history is mixed in with the **site's** history
- Some tags **imply** others, like `[jquery]` and `[javascript]` or `[android]` and `[java]`
- Users can be **grouped** based on activity
- Your **initial** answers weigh heavily in your grouping
- **Ignored** tags are ignored, **favorite** tags are considered

You can see the tags it thinks you'll be interested in on your [Tag Future Report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current). For me it seems like a pretty spot-on representation.

### ... but not completely

As noted in the replies [below the post](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/#comment-241), a number of **random** questions are thrown into the mix. This could be seen as a good thing or a bad thing:

- **Not** using random ones could narrow a user's scope; they might not learn new things
- **Too many** random ones would be a waste of time; users may truly not care about them

Personally, I think the ratio they're using works out pretty well. There aren't so many that I get bothered by it, but I occasionally see something interesting.